# if statement in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, gridview, aspx-user-control

attempting to set a radio button on a grid view via a condition.

```
 <input name="MyRadioButton" id="MyRadioButton<%=RadioNum() %>" type="radio" value='<%# Eval("TCMD_DCMNT_NBR") & Eval("VNDR_RQST_NBR") %>' style="left:auto" <% Eval("IsPostBack") {checked="checked"} {} %> /> 
                    <label for="MyRadioButton<%=RadioNumLabel() %>" style="display:none;"><%# Eval("TCMD_DCMNT_NBR") & Eval("VNDR_RQST_NBR") %></label>
                </ItemTemplate>
```

not quite sure how to set the checked to true when my IsPostBack is true.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you should be able to reference the [`Page.IsPostBack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx) property directly to set your attribute using a simple ternary operator :

```
<%= Page.IsPostBack ? "checked='checked'" : "" %>
```